# Error declaring sibling classes javascript (getElementsByClassName)

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have a problem trying to create an oriDomi object. I have narrowed it down to this algorithm:

Javascript:

```
for(var i=1;i<=slides;i++){
    fold[i-1]= new OriDomi(document.getElementsByClassName('slide')[i-1],{
        speed: 1200,
        rippple:2,
        shadingIntensity: 2,
        perspective:     800,   // smaller values exaggerate 3D distortion
        shading:         'hard'
    });
}
```

Even More narrowly to this line:

```
fold[i-1]= new OriDomi(document.getElementsByClassName('slide')[i-1],{
```

The problem is that it isn't cycling through the other slide classes on the page, instead it is stuck on the first instance of the class { AKA: ('slide')[0] }. Is there a problem  with my declaration? Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Not the problem, but why not `for (var i = 0; i < slides; i++)` so that you can just use `i` inside the loop instead of `i-1`?

Comment: Wow, sloppy coding. I'll change that now. Thanks. But that still won't change the error.

Comment: What is the actual error that you get?  And what is slides that you use in your for loop.  If it is a number, is it greater than 1?  If it is an array, what is its length?